# How to style django-multiselectfield with CSS

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am using 'django-multiselectfield' in my model form so users can select multiple 'areas' in my form. What I want to know now is how can I style the multiselectfield using css.

I have tried simply adding a class to the form field in my template like I normally do with all the other types of model fields, but no luck:

```
{% render_field form.area class="area" %}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is described in [`django-multiselectfield'](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield#customizing-templates) documentation.  Specifically,

> It is possible to customize the HTML of this widget in your form template. To do so, you will need to loop through form `{field}.field.choices`. Here is an example that displays the field label underneath/after the checkbox for a `MultiSelectField` called `providers`:

Comment: Thanks for this, Jason. I am still struggling to style the checkboxes on my django-multiselectfield. I can style the label for each checkbox (e.g. <label class="area_text">{{ text }}</label>) but when I try to style the checkbox itself (e.g. <input class="area_input" id="id_providers_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="{{ form.area.name }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ value }}"{% if value in checked_area %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>), it won't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of what i did.

```
{% for field in form %}  
     <div class="fieldWrapper">{{ field.errors }}
     <input  type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}"  name="{{ field.html_name }}"  id="{{field.id_for_label}}"   class="col-12 input-login" placeholder="{{field.label}}"  >
     {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
     {% endif %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you can customise the field as if it is a simple html input field.
This [page](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html) has a wonderful detailed explanation. Kudos to Vitor

------edit-----

Almost forgot. This is the example for normal forms. You have to go through the official docs of django-multiselectfield to get field attribute names, and replace the respective attributes

Comment: Thanks for this, Vipin. I am still struggling to style the checkboxes on my django-multiselectfield. I can style the label for each checkbox (e.g. <label class="area_text">{{ text }}</label>) but when I try to style the checkbox itself (e.g. <input class="area_input" id="id_providers_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="{{ form.area.name }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ value }}"{% if value in checked_area %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>), it won't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First, use django default form, and inspect the code in browser, to see rendered plain html code, note these down, especially input attributes and form_id, input id etc, then customize your form, and make sure all the above attributes appear. Eg checkbox id, value etc.

Comment: Once i was stuck in a form, i put in all forms but forgot to set field.value

Comment: Hi Vipin, I've tried this but still no luck. My current code: `{% for value, text in form.area.field.choices %}
        <div class="area_div">
                <input id="area_input" name="{{ form.area.name }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ value }}">
                <label class="area_text">{{ text }}</label>
        </div>
{% endfor %}` and here is my CSS `.area_text{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#area_input{
    border-radius: 0px;
}` I can style the label (area_text) fine but I just cant manage to style the input checkboxes at all! Any help would be great!

Comment: As i said earlier in on xmas vacation. But from first looks, don't give id explicitly, can you do a simple form.as_p and compare it currently rendered code, just browser inspect both code, side by side and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you render the form manually and loop through it.

Say you have a Choice model with a foreignkey to a Question model, you could do it like this:

```
<form class="qform" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p class="title">{{ form.question }}</p>
    {% for choice in form.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ choice }}" id="{{ choice }}{{ forloop.counter }}" 
                value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="{{ choice }}{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice }}</label>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

You can reference the input and label in your `style.css` like:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    some: stuffs...;
}

label {
    some: stuffs...;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi bunya, I've tried this but still no luck. My current code: `{% for value, text in form.area.field.choices %}
        <div class="area_div">
                <input id="area_input" name="{{ form.area.name }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ value }}">
                <label class="area_text">{{ text }}</label>
        </div>
{% endfor %}` and here is my CSS `.area_text{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#area_input{
    border-radius: 0px;
}` I can style the label (area_text) fine but I just cant manage to style the input checkboxes at all! Any help would be great!

Comment: @WillDpard can you post the coce from your models, views and forms?